# MODX MIGX data in chunk

Tags: json, modx, modx-revolution, modx-chunks

I have created similar table to this one 
http://rtfm.modx.com/display/ADDON/MIGX.Simple+opening+hours+table

I have successfully exported data to resource, but i want to show it in a chunk so i can display it in getresources.

I use getresources to display resources and besides title and intro text i would like to show datesTV data.

I use template chunk for migx:

```
 [[+date:notempty=`<td>[[+date:strtotime:date=`%d.%m.%Y, %H.%M`]]</td>`:default=`<td colspan="2">No show!</td>`]]
```

If i use this in other chunk for getresources [[+tv.datesTV]] i get this array out:

```
 [{"MIGX_id":"1","date":"2012-10-28 21:00:00"},{"MIGX_id":"2","date":"2012-10-28 01:45:00"},{"MIGX_id":"3","date":"2012-10-30 02:45:00"}]
```

How can I display this data as it should be in a chunk.

Answer (score 1):

Ok here you can se how my snippet looks like..

```
<?php
$strJSON = $modx->resource->getTVValue('spored');
$arrJSON = $modx->fromJSON($strJSON);

foreach($arrJSON as $arrJSONDataSet)
{
  foreach($arrJSONDataSet as $key => $value)
 {
    echo $key . ' => ';
    echo $value;
    echo '<br />';
  }
}
```

Comment: Try adding a `var_dump($arrJSONDataSet)` before the second `foreach()` as the PHP error seems to indicate that it is not an array

Comment: I get same error. I I use this var_dump with (Ditch the second foreach statement and echo $key and $value for $arrJSON instead) what you said before I get nothing out.

Comment: I think I solved my problem with "ShowTV Snippet". I get my data from tv in a chunk with this call [[!ShowTv? &tvID=`3` &resourceID=`[[+id]]`]]. But now I have another problem. I get only raw data out and i dont have an idea how to corectly display it. I get out [{"MIGX_id":"1","date":"2012-11-21 22:40.....

Comment: any ideas on how to convert this json data?

Answer (score 0):

With MIGX you need a snippet to parse and format the raw TV data as it's stored as JSON.

For a rough example of how to do this, refer back to the link you mentioned and try the getImageList snippet:
http://rtfm.modx.com/display/ADDON/MIGX.Simple+opening+hours+table#MIGX.Simpleopeninghourstable-ParsingtheData

You'll need to include that snippet call in your getResources chunk which is going to be really inefficient; it would be better to code up a custom snippet to retrieve the necessary data.

But see how that goes first...

Comment: so I created snippet like this:
     <?php
     $strJSON = $modx->resource->getTVValue('spored');
     $arrJSON = $modx->fromJSON($strJSON);
     foreach($arrJSON as $arrJSONDataSet)
     {
     foreach($arrJSONDataSet as $key => $value)
     {
     /* echo $key . ' => ';*/
     echo $value;
     echo '<br />';
     }
     }

But when I use it I get this error (what am I doing wrong?):

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/content/57/7560357/html/metropolcom/core/cache/includes/elements/modsnippet/52.include.cache.php on line 10

Comment: Ditch the second foreach statement and echo $key and $value for $arrJSON instead.

Comment: If I use it like that I get the same error in chunk and in template 0 => Array 1 => Array 2 => Array. Any other idea?

Comment: I can't read your snippet easily like that. Which `foreach()` statement is on line 10?

Comment: I posted the code like anwser to question so you can see how my snippet looks like.